# How can I find all elements that matches the category array item

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

I'm using Prisma with Nextjs

My data is stored in a database that looks like

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6444deb138cc17820d78d9f9"
  },
  "type": "youtube#video",
  "category": [
    "reactjs",
    "all"
  ],
  "videoId": "4UZrsTqkcW4",
  "title": "Full React Course 2020 - Learn Fundamentals, Hooks, Context API, React Router, Custom Hooks",
  "description": "Learn the basics of React in this comprehensive course. You will learn about fundamentals, hooks, context API, react router, ...",
  "thumbnailUrl": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4UZrsTqkcW4/mqdefault.jpg",
  "publishedAt": {
    "$date": "2020-10-06T14:16:07.000Z"
  },
  "channelTitle": "freeCodeCamp.org",
  "channelId": "UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ"
}
```

This is the schema I'm using

```
model Video {
  id             String        @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  type           String
  category       String[]
  videoId        String        @unique
  playlistItems  PlaylistItem[]
  title          String
  description    String
  thumbnailUrl   String
  publishedAt    DateTime
  channelTitle   String
  channelId      String
  details        VideoDetails?
}
```

I'm fetching data

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

import prisma from "@/libs/prismadb";

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    const { q } = req.query;
    console.log(String(q));
    const data = await prisma.video.findMany({
      where: {
        type: "youtube#video",
        category: {
          in: [String(q)],
        },
      },
    });
    res.status(200).json(data);
  } catch (error: any) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

using the above code but getting the error-

```
{
    "message": "\nInvalid `prisma.video.findMany()` invocation:\n\n{\n  where: {\n    type: 'youtube#video',\n    category: {\n      in: [\n      ~~\n        'undefined'\n      ]\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nUnknown arg `in` in where.category.in for type StringNullableListFilter. Available args:\n\ntype StringNullableListFilter {\n  equals?: List<String> | Null\n  has?: String | Null\n  hasEvery?: List<String>\n  hasSome?: List<String>\n  isEmpty?: Boolean\n}\n\n"
}
```

how can a fix this error and can get items that contains the requested category?